# Figure reference management

Tags: graphics, bibliographies, floats

I'm writing an academic report and it is required that I include my figure/picture references (almost exclusively URLs).  Already tried to use BibLatex to make sub-bibliographies but that proved to be too unstable.
Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Do you need to include URLs that are clickable? Then the `hyperref` would provide `\href`. Or do you want citations that include URLs or references within your document? In that case I don't understand the URL requirement. Or something else entirely? As you can see, I have trouble to understand your question.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. What I meant is: I need a way to manage picture sources which are mostly taken from websites. I tried using BibLatex to make sub-bibliographies but it was too unstable to be usable...

Comment: I'm intrigued that you found `biblatex` to be too unstable. For me and many other, it's great.

Comment: Perhaps 'unstable' is not the best word for what was going on. Also, in retrospect, it might be my editor that is bugging. But what happened was that I made two sub-bibliographies, one for text references and one for picture references. I used `keywords` for splitting them up and it would work once or twice and after that it would just generate some errors (don't have them right now).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`figbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/figbib) package provides a way to manage figure references in BibTeX databases. A small example:

#### document.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{figbib}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
The Stack Exchange logo is shown in \fbref{stackexchange}.
\fbEpsfig{stackexchange}{5cm}{htbp}
\fbList{figures} 
\end{document}
```

#### figures.bib

```
@FIG{stackexchange,
    main = {The Stack Exchange logo},
    add = {additional description},
    file = {StackExchange},
    source = {\url{http://stackexchange.com/img/StackExchange.png}}
}
```

#### Compiled output result:

[image: picture of the compiled output]

Don't worry about the name of the `\fbEpsfig` command, it works fine with `PNG` or `PDF` images, too. More information on how to use `figbib` can be found in the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/figbib/figbib_doc.pdf).

You may want to additionally use the `figbib_add` package from the [`thesis-titlepage-fhac`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thesis-titlepage-fhac) bundle: It gives you the possibilty to manage figures created for example with `pgf`/`TikZ` in the same way as external images with `figbib`:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A circle}
    \label{figbib:circle} % prefix "figbib:" is necessary
    \fbEntry{circle}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll use it in my next report, as now I've discarded the figure sources.

Comment: Now that I have tried using FigBiB it seems that it only supports the latex compiler, not pdfLatex compiler.

Comment: @benregn The MWE I provided above works fine with `pdflatex` for me. As I pointed out, the package was obviously written for `latex` (hence the `\fbEpsfig` command name), but it should still work correctly with `pdflatex` and `PNG` or `PDF` graphics files. What error messages do you get?

Comment: Thanks for this answer @diabonas. However, I copied your code to an empty folder and ran latex and pdflatex (tried both) on document.tex. In both cases, I receive the following warning and thus no figures in the document:
`LaTeX Warning: Reference 'figbib:stackexchange' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.`

`Package figbib Warning: Figure 'stackexchange' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.`
I am using Linux Mint 17 with Tex Live 2015. Is it still working on your machine?