# List of figures: source below image caption?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions, tocloft

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and currently working on a paper. In my list of figures, I'd like to have a structure like this:

```
    Fig. 1: <Title of figure> . . . 1
            <source_of_image.jpg>

    Fig. 2: <Title of figure> . . . 2
            <source_.png>
```

Can anyone think of a way of doing this? Basically, I just need some kind of reference to the actual figure. I'm using the `caption` package, so the captions of my figures look like this:

```
    \caption[source of image]{Title of image}
```

By using the `tocloft` package, I've already managed to tweak a few things; but I'm yet to find out how I can use both source and title of a figure in the list of figures (apart from creating the whole list manually).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A couple of remarks: First, it would be helpful if you provided a bit more information on what you're trying to achieve. It's not common (though certainly not necessarily wrong either!) to provide an image (thumbnail-sized?) of each figure in List of Figures. Second, I've deleted the final line of your question -- in this group, we tend not to thank people in advance. Upvoting (and, if appropriate, accepting) their answers is the reward all of us crave. :-)

Comment: Alright, thanks for your remarks.  You actually misunderstood me: I do not want to put the actual source image into the LOF - what I want is to put the source there, e. g. `http://de.wikipedia.org/...`.

Comment: Related question: [Figure reference management](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13667/3323)

Comment: @Mico Do you happen to know if anyone ever did the thumbnail thing? I lack the imagination to know beforehand whether this is a good idea (it's one that brought me here anyway). Might be practical and look cool. Might also be cocky and look cheesy. So if I could have a look at such a LoF before investing any time in making it work, that would be quite nice indeed.

Comment: @Christian -- please consider posting a new question to inquire about this subject. It's not very likely that many people will notice your question if it's posed as a comment to an existing answer. Thanks. If you want, you can always provide a link back to the existing question to provide context.

Comment: @Mico yeah, that would have been my next step (and I now did so: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82858/how-to-get-thumbnails-in-a-list-of-figures) but I wanted to ask you personally first because it looked as if you might already have seen what you thought the OP was talking of :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is basically tocloft's `\cftchapterprecis`, but in the list of figures instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    {\leftskip\cftfigindent
     \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
     \rightskip\@tocrmarg
     \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
    \caption{World Targets in Megadeaths}
    \figsource{BLAND Corporation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you use hyperref, you can make the sources into clickable links:

```
\figsource{\url{file:alameda_afb.tiff}}
```

Comment: Works just the way I wanted it to :-)