# How to get thumbnails in a list of figures?

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

To be honest, I'm not sure if I really want this because I can't imagine how exactly it would look. But maybe someone is interested in this, too, or even has already written code to achieve this: it might be practical or interesting to have small thumbnail previews of a figure in the list of figures next to the caption.

This has already been briefly discussed here [List of figures: source below image caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45083/list-of-figures-source-below-image-caption#comment92355_45083) but without any result so if anybody wants to give it a shot or has already done so: yay! :)

---

See [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82865/13450) for an example image of how this might look.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Macro `\addtocontents` allows something to put into the list of figures:

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{myimage}
  \caption{My figure caption}
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    \protect\centerline{%
      \protect\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{myimage}%
    }%
  }%
\end{figure}
```

Variant with vertically centered image between number of figure and caption text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\lofthumbsize}
\setlength{\lofthumbsize}{2em}

\newif\iflofimage
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\lofimage}[2][]{%
  \iflofimage
    $\vcenter to \lofthumbsize{\vss%
      \hbox to \lofthumbsize{\hss\includegraphics[{width=\lofthumbsize,height=\lofthumbsize,keepaspectratio=true,#1}]{#2}\hss}%
    \vss}$%
    \quad
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
\lofimagetrue
\listoffigures
\lofimagefalse
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\lofimage{foo}Hello World}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\lofimage{bar}Foobar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This looks like this:

[image: example list of figures]

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was this easy. I tried something like this: `\newcommand{\figureincludegraphics}[2][\empty]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}{\includegraphics{#2}}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\centerline{\protect\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5em,keepaspectratio=true]{#2}}}}` which works but looks pretty awful to be honest. Maybe instead of having a large picture above the respective LoF line, having one at the beginning of the line or between number and caption would look better. Is there a similarly easy way to achieve this?

Comment: @Christian `\leftline` instead of `\centerline` puts the image at the beginning of the line. If `\addtocontents` is given _after_ `\caption`, then the image is put _below_ the respective LoF line.

Comment: No, `\leftline` doesn't work somehow :/ It does shift the image to the left but it's still in a separate line.

Comment: Ok, your new code basically works as expected. Great :) I'll post a picture of the result tomorrow and when I find the time I will have to some polishing like a bounding box along both axes without messing up the alignment and a minimal vertical space between images. Right now, tall images touch each other and generally increase the linespread too much, which both doesn't look pretty.

Comment: I added an example LoF to your answer. Obviously, the variance in the line heights is the main downer currently. In principle it looks almost surprisingly ok though I have to say. I'm astonished nobody ever did this as far as I know. If anybody wants to discuss whether this is a typographical disaster or actually a nice feature, I'd welcome your opinion.

Comment: Finally got around to give the code some more or less final touches. Hope it's ok I just changed the code in your answer. If there's a more elegant way to do this, I'd be very keen to learn it :)

Comment: Holy cow you guys, this is awesome! Have you considered turning this into a package?

Comment: @doncherry Flagged as you requested. For a package I personally find the explicit `\lofimage` solution still too unwieldy. Something automatic would be nicer but also much, much more complex. So maybe some package would be better than none at all; I don't know.

Comment: @Christian - This code works wonders!! I've adapted the code for all 100+ figures in my project! Is there any way to adapt the code to work with the List of Tables as well, recognizing that I'd have to make screen shots of each table and save them along with the List of Figures (jpg and png) files ... thanks!

Comment: @Christian - P.S. I increased \setlength{\lofthumbsize}{2em} to {3em} for clarity ... works GREAT!

Answer (score 6):

The solution of Heiko looks nice and is easy to implement, however it does not produce exactly what I want. On the printout, the thumbnails are much too small imo. Increasing the size results in rather empty pages...

Here is my adapted version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\lofthumbsize}
\setlength{\lofthumbsize}{8em}

\newif\iflofimage
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\lofimage}[2][]{%
\iflofimage
$\vspace*{-1.2\baselineskip}
  \hbox to .7\columnwidth{\hss\raisebox{1\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[{width=\lofthumbsize,keepaspectratio=true,#1}]{#2}}\hss}%
$%
\vspace*{0.2\baselineskip}
\newline
\fi
\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
\lofimagetrue

\twocolumn
\begingroup
\let\onecolumn\twocolumn
\listoffigures
\endgroup
\onecolumn

\lofimagefalse
\begin{figure}
\caption{\lofimage{foo}Hello World}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\lofimage{bar}Foobar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here is how it looks like:
[List of Figures with Thumbs http://www.img-load.de/images-i1536106bumrve.png](http://www.img-load.de/images-i1536106bumrve.png)

Comment: That looks pretty nice. I think I'd also introduce a `height=` argument to prevent portrait images from becoming too large but overall, this seems pretty neat :) One thing is troubling though .... collision avoidance in planes doesn't even use hex grids? ;)

Comment: Since I have landscapes only I skipped the height to have all pics aligned above each other... but you'll need height for portraits. Concerning the hex grids, that's the related work only - I know better :)

Comment: The link in the this question is broken.  Please include images directly in the post.