# Graphical index based on figures? (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, indexing

At the end of my Beamer presentation, I would like a slide that contains thumbnails of all the images presented in my slide. These images would be linked to the slide which they appeared on. Basically, it's a graphical index of the presentation. That way, I could find the slide by simply clicking on the right picture when someone asked a question.

This would also be very helpful for a thesis/textbook, but for now I'm concerned with Beamer.

I've only seen this done once (in a textbook), but it made everything significantly easier when trying to find a particular figure you had seen before.

Has anyone tried doing anything like this? I'm sure I could brute-force it by simply including pictures at smaller scales, but I though there might be a proper way to do it.

Comment: Do you want thumbnails of the *slides*, or thumbnails of the *images/figures* in the slides?

Comment: Kevin: Thumbnails of the images/figures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\listofthumbnails` uses the LaTeX's kernel `\@starttoc` to build the list on its own frame. Simply call iy in the place you want the list to appear in your document. The `\thufigure` command has three arguments: the optional argument can pass the standard options to `\includegraphics`; the second one is for the name of the file containing the image, and the third one for the caption:

```
\thufigure[<options>]{<image file>}{<caption>}
```

This command actually includes the thumbnail in the list and also uses the `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` mechanism to make the thumbnails clickable to the original figures.

Of course, the same procedure can be applied (except for `\begin{frame}`, `\end{frame}`, `\frametitle`) to any other document class.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofthumbnails{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Figure Thumbnails}
\@starttoc{lft}
\end{frame}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\thufigure[3][]{%
  \begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
  \caption{#3}
  \hypertarget{fig\thefigure}{}
  \end{figure}
  \addcontentsline{lft}{figure}{\protect\hyperlink{fig\thefigure}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{#2}}}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\thufigure[width=3cm]{cat}{Some caption for a cat}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\thufigure[width=4cm]{ctanlion}{CTAN lion by Duane Bibby}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\thufigure[height=3cm]{chinita}{A nice bug}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\thufigure[width=5cm]{image-1}{A house}
\end{frame}

\listofthumbnails

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonalo, this looks perfect. However, when I try to compile with PDFLaTeX, I get the following errors: "\beamer@presort #1#2#3->\long \def \beamer@todo
{#1}\def \beamer@ospec {}\be..." and "! Argument of \beamerx@\includegraphics has an extra }." I don't understand the first error, but I've checked several times and I can't find an extra }.

Comment: Are you compiling the exact same code I posted? I ask you because I use pdflatex and I got no problems, so if you are getting errors, I would need to see an example reproducing the problem which you can add as an edit to your question.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the original code, modified code, etc. Here is a screen cap. of the code (and errors). http://i.imagebanana.com/img/0sz3moc1/Selection_024.png

Comment: @user29283 And the *exact* code I posted gives you the error message (of course, after using some of your own images)?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded 4 random images and named them according to your code (to prevent modifying the code); however, I am still experiencing the errors listed in the screen cap. above.

Comment: Which version of beamer are you using? Do you have an updated LaTeX system installed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8414/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-user29283)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a LaTeX solution for this.

Make an PDF of any normal Beamer presentation, but instead of open it with Acrobat Reader or any other viewer, use [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/). That's all.

In Impressive, you just have to hit the `[Tab]` key and the current slide will smoothly zoom out, revealing a thumbnail grid of all pages. Now you can select one of the pages, click on it, and watch it zoom back in.

The link above show this overview screen with a Beamer presentation, but you can do this with any PDF, made with LaTeX or without LaTeX.

For other documents that presentations, if you don't want a thumbnail of each page but only of the figures, take a look to 
[How to get thumbnails in a list of figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82858/how-to-get-thumbnails-in-a-list-of-figures)

Comment: Fran: This seems like it could work well for presentations; however, I am still interested in creating a graphical index for a thesis.

Comment: @user29283, this work with any document type if you want a thumbnail of each page. In other case, see the edited answer.