# Graphic Gallery instead of thumbnails in a list of figures?

Tags: floats, lists

Is-it possible to do a Graphic Gallery instead of a normal list or thumbnails in a list of figures ? (as in the picture in example)
The result is dissimilar of this solution : [How to get thumbnails in a list of figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82858/how-to-get-thumbnails-in-a-list-of-figures)

Many thanks,
Mat

[image]
Source : https://www.aps.org/energyefficiencyreport/report/aps-energyreport.pdf