# Numbering the list of figures in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, tocbibind

So I'm having a slight problem with the `\listoffigures` command and the way LaTeX makes the table of contents. In my preamble I'm using `\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}`
 because I want to include the bibliography in the ToC (and with a section-number as well). However, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same for list of figures. The package tocbibind sadly don't have an option like `numlof` and all results on google either don't give me a working result or has something to do with "how to manually add an item in the ToC", which isn't really what I'm looking for.

In short, how do I add the listoffigures in the ToC with a number attached to it.

Just to add, I can add the list of figures in the ToC without problems, but I'd like a section-number as well. I'm using the `article` class by the way.

EDIT: Silly me, I was also using the `tocloft`package, in order to make a way to list the source of a bunch of images. The process is described at [List of figures: source below image caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45083/list-of-figures-source-below-image-caption)

It seems the two methods conflict each other. I'd really like to have both the numbered LoF in the ToC and a way to list the source of each figure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done adding the following lines to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you are also using `tocloft`, you have to inform `tocloft` that you want to use your custom titles by passing the option `titles` when loading it:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
\tocsection
\tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    {\leftskip\cftfigindent
     \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
     \rightskip\@tocrmarg
     \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{test}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{World Targets in Megadeaths}
    \figsource{BLAND Corporation}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Alright silly me, I was also using the `tocloft`package, in order to make a way to list the source of a bunch of images. The process is described at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45083/list-of-figures-source-below-image-caption

I'd really like to have both the numbered LoF in the ToC and a way to list the source of each figure.

I've updated the OP.

Comment: @Argo I've edited the answer. See if now it is OK.

Comment: It works! Thanks a ton! Out of curiosity, does one "just" look at the code for each package in order to create macros, that make them work together?

Comment: @Argo Usually, when one uses conflicting packages, tries to find the best compromise.