# Indentation on Figure source on list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I adapted this [answer for article class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45095/54029) to work with memoir class. The only issue I now have is that the first line of the source text is overly indented. I want to have the figure source text flush with the figure caption text.

This is my MWE

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    {\leftskip=\cftfigureindent
    \advance\leftskip \cftfigurenumwidth
    \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
     \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image}
\caption{This is a picture}
\figsource{This is a short source}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image}
\caption{This is an image}
\figsource{This is a really really really really really really really really really long source of over a line long to show the indent after one line}
\label{image1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't ask... just try `\advance\leftskip 0.38\cftfigurenumwidth` instead of `\advance\leftskip \cftfigurenumwidth`. As you can understand I was just playing...

Comment: I suppose you want second line the same indented. Don't you?

Comment: I assume memoir loads tocloft automatically, since \cftfigureindent etc. are defined.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, memoir includes the functionality of tocloft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By playing but I knew it wasn't so difficult:

Wait for the explanation (from someone else:P):

Solution:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    {\leftskip=\cftfigurenumwidth
    \advance \leftskip \cftfigureindent
    \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
     \figsourcefont\noindent#1\protect\par}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit after John Kormylo's comment. (Contains the real explanation too. Find it there)**
Before edit I had minus in advancing (so reduced) the indent but it happened to be zero and my code was working by luck.

**Old wrong explanation**
And the explanation is that we have to use noindent to have same indent in all lines and that the length we needed is the figurenumwidth minus the figureindent on the section since we have to go from the start of the line figurenumwidth right and then go back left by transacting the indent.

Comment: In this case \cftfigureindent=0pt.  The original calculation is more general.  \cftfigurenumwidth for the figure number (left justified) and \cftfigureindent for any additonal gap.

Comment: I had tried to use \noindent myself but had put it in the wrong place in my code.